# Fusion Tables, Phonegap and Static Maps API

Tags: cordova, google-fusion-tables, google-maps-static-api

I'm building an Phonegap app (iOS and Android) that uses Google Map V3 JS API and Fusion Tables. The core of the  app is to display a "live" map of wildlife sightings - people can add and view sightings through map / app etc.

The core functionality works fine. But we have 2 performance issues:
1. Due to the "live" nature of Google Maps and our map content (coming directly from Fusion Tables) the map loads quite slowly.
2. Users will sometimes have no phone network coverage (remote locations). As per problem above, the map doesn't work offline.

So we need a way to try and help the map to work offline, where there is no network coverage.

I've spent a lot of time looking at alternatives but (being only self-taught technically) I struggle to get to an answer...

- Can we use Google Static Maps with Fusion Tables? So the baseline Google Map is a static map but we can still show Fusion Table layers, markers etc over it?
- Can we combine offline, non Google Maps with Fusion Tables? So we would build our own offline map using, e.g. TileMill, and the Fusion Tables layer would show on top of that?
- What types of above offline maps would be best to use with PhoneGap and Fusion Tables? There seem to be complications using PhoneGap and TileMill which we're struggling to overcome. Does anyone know of an alternative of successful deployments or alternatives that we could look at?

Apologies for all the questions. Any and all input very much appreciated.

Rob

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider other technologies, your question states you are using google maps API and fusion tables, but perhaps you should view those statements as assumption on your part that may need reconsideration. I would suggest looking at leaflet.js (http://leafletjs.com/) as an alternative. Why I am telling you this I cannot fathom, because I'm building an application that will be in direct competition with yours, from the sounds of it. Best of luck.